# What is the max write speed to a firebase realtime database shard?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

To rephrase the question, does the 64mb/min apply to the entire database or to a single shard?  So is it possible to get more write bandwidth by sharding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Throughput and access limits for the Firebase Realtime Database are per shard. So you can increase the throughput of your project by having multiple shards.